# Is dirty required as an argument to getValidationContext as described in the bootstrap-vue documentation?

Tags: validation, bootstrap-vue, vee-validate

I have a question about the bootstrap-vue description of the vee-validate v3.

https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/reference/validation#veevalidate-v3

The documentation uses dirty as the argument to getValidationContext, but this doesn't seem necessary since validated will never be false when dirty is true.

```js
getValidationState({ dirty, validated, valid = null }) {
  return dirty || validated ? valid : null;
},
```

case1. not yet entered

```
dirty: false
validated: false
valid: true
result: null
```

case2. valid input

```
dirty: true
validated: true
valid: true
result: true
```

case3. invalid input

```
dirty: true
validated: true
valid: false
result: false
```

Could you tell me the case where validated is false when dirty is true?

Or is dirty not necessary?